# Read asterisk dialplan command from file

Tags: command, asterisk, execute

I would like to dynamically read an asterisk dialplan command from a (dynamically generated) file. Note: Within this file there can be a Dial() or a Playback() command, maybe later more than these two.

Is there any asterisk command or command combination that allows this? Something like

```
exten => 1234,1,ReadAndExecuteCommandFromFile("/foo/bar")
```

whereas "/foo/bar" contains one (1) line like

```
Dial(SIP/123456@provider)
```

or

```
Playback(something)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is called AGI - Asterisk Gateway Interface. It will allow you to interact with the channel, in a synchronous manner. However, the "Commands" will be slightly different.

There are multiple scripting tool kits for AGI. If you are familiar with PHP, I suggest you have a look at PHPAGI, as it will give you the most bang for your buck in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way use AGI is do like this:

```
exten => 1234,1,AGI(/bin/cat /foo/bar)
```

in /foo/bar file you need place AGI command

```
EXEC Dial SIP/123456@provider
```

or

```
EXEC Playback somefile
```

However more effective way use func_odbc function+dialplan or full AGI stack(better fast-AGI)